# c# Get value (text) of a bound textbox in a gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, textbox

I have bound textboxes in a gridview. Code to create the gridview cell:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtWLA" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WLA") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I'm trying to loop through my gridview and get the values in the textboxes. I've tried several variations of this:

```
 txtValue =  row.Cells[1].FindControl("txtWLA").Text;   //I've tried "text" and "textbox" too
```

But no matter what I try, I keep getting an error telling me that the 'text' value is wrong. Here's the error:

```
'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no 
extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 
'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found
```

I'm baffled. Every resource I try tells me that .Text is the right way to get the contents of a textbox. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of FindControl() is `System.Web.UI.Control` and it does not have a property with the name `Text`

If you know what the actual type is, just cast and access it:

txtValue =  (row.Cells[1].FindControl("txtWLA") as TextBox).Text;

Comment: The best answers don't just solve the problem, they explain the problem.